# I am doing a small project in Android Studio and i am using SQLite .There is an error near the insert operation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Original";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="Register";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID="id";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME="name";
    //private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL="email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PHONENUMBER="number";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD="password";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context mcontext)
    {
        super(mcontext , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String CREATE_REGISTER_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + COLUMN_UNAME + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT " + " ) ";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_REGISTER_TABLE);
    }

    public void insertContact(Original c)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
       // int count=cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID,c.getID());
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME,c.getName());
        //values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,c.getPassw());
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER,c.getNumber());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null , values);
        db.close();
    }



    public String searchPass(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT "+COLUMN_UNAME + "AND " +COLUMN_PASSWORD +"FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery(query , null);

        String a,b;
        b="not found";
        if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                a=mCursor.getString(0);

                if(a.equals(name))
                {
                    b=mCursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
    {
        String query="DROP TABLE IF EXITS"+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

The Error is shown at the `db.insert()` operation.
The main purpose is to add the details into the database name Original with the table name register

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: "The Error is shown at the db.insert() operation" -- if you mean that your app is crashing, please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with the crash. Please note that closing the database after an individual operation (e.g., `insertContact()`) usually is not a good plan, as other threads in your app may be relying upon the open database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is sort of OK, I have run it once (well twice using a single `Original` instance to purposefully generate the `UNIQUE constraint` error). However it will fail if  the Original object's **ID** is not unique. You would get an error along the lines of :-

```
07-18 06:32:46.208 2819-2819/? E/SQLiteLog: (1555) abort at 11 in [INSERT INTO Register(number,name,password,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: Register.id
07-18 06:32:46.208 2819-2819/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting number=0312341234 name=Fred password=password id=10
```

If this isn't the error, then perhaps it is because you have changed the table's structure (e.g. added(most likely)/removed columns) without deleting the database (either deleting the App's Data or uninstalling the App). This is a common mistake that people make as they don't realise that the `onCreate` method is only automatically called when the database is created.

I suspect the latter as there is a sign that you have changed the table structure as per the commented out line `//values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());`

P.S. you should close the cursor in the `searchPass` method before returning e.g. code `mCursor.close();`

If netiher of the above are the issue, then you should edit your question and include the log/stacktrace that details the error and also probably the code from the invoking activity e.g. (the code I used) :-

```
            Original ori = new Original(10l,"Fred","password","fred@email.com","0312341234");
            DatabaseHelper dbhlp = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            dbhlp.insertContact(ori);
```

Comment: Yes i got it.The insertion is successful. There was an issue with the Ids unique constraint.